# What to do when my AKKA Actor dies

Tags: scala, akka

Just for discussion here,

I was thinking AKKA is great for writing distributed systems but however if your Supervisor and Actors are all in one machine your distributed system will not be highly available. If the machine goes down the whole distributed system goes down with it.

So how about i put the Supervisor in one machine and all the Actors in separate machines. So if one Actor dies there are still others to handle the work. If i bring up a replacement machine. How can the Supervisor know that there is this new machine that can house a new Actor?

Ultimately the Supervisor tree leads to a Root Supervisor. What if the machine that houses the Root Supervisor dies? Does this make it the weakest link in the whole distributed system? How about having an additional Root Supervisor node that one can fail over to? How about having several and have a load balancer in front of all the Root Supervisor to distribute the load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems are reoccurring and are solved by various cluster tools in Akka, that are all built on the core cluster APIs.

Cluster singleton allow you to have a single instance of an actor in an entire cluster, if the node is downed, the singleton actors will start on a new node. See docs here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-singleton.html#cluster-singleton

Sharding, as mentioned by László is for when you have a high number of actors that you want to maintain one of in the cluster. Docs here: 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-sharding.html

Both of these nicely fits together with Akka Persistence, to make an actor arrive at the same state as a previous actor instance on another node.

If you want your actors to be available at all times, you cannot achieve that at the same time as "having only one" (essentially the consistency vs availability problem), but you can use Akka Distributed Data for always available but eventually consistent state. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/distributed-data.html

You could of course also build your own tools using Actors and the Cluster APIs if none of the existing fits your use case (I wouldn't say it is trivial though ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is quite some documentation on the general topic of distributing Actor systems over multiple machines, communicating over the network:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/index-network.html

That said, while it is possible to remotely supervise an Actor, you correctly surmised that it does not yield much additional resilience. Rather, use [Cluster Sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-sharding.html) to ensure that copies of workers exist on multiple machines, and use a simple cluster-aware `ActorRef` to send message to them from another machine (without a supervision relationship).